# Regular expression Spring data mongodb repositories

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

Good morning,

I´m trying to combine regular expression with Spring data mongodb repository using Query annotation.
What I want is search one substring inside one string attribute of my mongo document.
I have been looking in google and here, but I did not find anything elegant, and I was wondering if Spring data has something official about this using the repositories.

Regards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems like an old question, so maybe you've already had a solution but here how I handled the same issue :

```
@Query(value = "{'title': {$regex : ?0, $options: 'i'}}")
Foo findByTitleRegex(String regexString);
```

using the `/?0/` notation won't work since Spring Data places a String value with quotes

Comment: Hi @Alper how to use $caseInsensitive flag in a criteria query. This is the example of a query I've in my firstName = Criteria.where("firstName").regex(fullName, "i") the query doesn't returns case insensitive results, the results are like Upper case results first and  lowercase results after, I want to try with caseinsensitive flag set to true, is there any way to include it in a criteria code.