# Spring Data mongo case insensitive like query

Tags: full-text-search, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I want to make a text search case insensitive with regex query with `spring-data mongo` .

For example in Oracle :

`select * from user where lower(username) like '%ab%'`

How can i make this query  with `spring-data mongo` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can try something like below. Assumes you have a `User` pojo class.

Using MongoTemplate

`i` option for case insensitive:

```
Criteria regex = Criteria.where("username").regex(".*ab.*", "i");      
mongoOperations.find(new Query().addCriteria(regex), User.class);
```

Using MongoRepository (Case sensitive)

```
List<User> users = userRepository.findByUserNameRegex(".*ab.*");

interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
     List<User> findByUserNameRegex(String userName);
}
```

Using MongoRepository with Query dsl (Case sensitive)

```
List<User> users = userRepository.findByQuery(".*ab.*");

interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
     @Query("{'username': {$regex: ?0 }})")
     List<User> findByQuery(String userName);
}
```

For Non-Regex based query you can now utilize case insensitive search/sort through collation with locale and strength set to primary or secondary:

```
Query query = new Query(filter);
query.collation(Collation.of("en").
                  strength(Collation.ComparisonLevel.secondary()));
mongoTemplate.find(query,clazz,collection);
```

Answer (score 25):

I know this is an old question. I just found the solution in another post.
Use $regex and $options as below:

```java
@Query(value = "{'title': {$regex : ?0, $options: 'i'}}")
Foo findByTitleRegex(String regexString);
```

see the original answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068401

Comment: If your regex is 'test', this will return documents with titles like:    test1, test2 etc.

Answer (score 6):

```
@Repository
public interface CompetenceRepository extends MongoRepository<Competence, String> {

    @Query("{ 'titre' : { '$regex' : ?0 , $options: 'i'}}")
    List<Competence> findAllByTitreLikeMotcle(String motCle);
}
```

Should works perfectly ,it works in my projects.for words in French too

Answer (score 1):

In repository pattern I tried this and worked

@Query("{ 'username' :  ?0 }.collation( { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } )")

User findByUserName(String name);

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, provided you have set up it right, I would add something like this in your repository method:

{'username': {$regex: /ab/i }})

> @Query("{'username': {$regex: /?1/i }})")
>
> List findUsersByUserName(String userName);

Answer (score 0):

For like query on numeric fields (int or double)

```
db.players.find({
  $and: [{
      "type": {
        $in: ["football"]
      }
    },
    {
      $where : "/^250.*/.test(this.salary)"
    }]
})
```

See the detailed code: [Spring Boot mongodb like query on int/double using mongotemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542795/spring-boot-mongodb-like-query-on-numeric-fields-integer-double)

Answer (score 0):

```
String tagName = "apple";

Query query = new Query();
query.limit(10);
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("tagName").regex(tagName));

mongoOperation.find(query, Tags.class);
```

Reference - https://mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-like-query-example/