# Spring boot mongoDB like query on numeric fields-Integer / Double

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I want to make LIKE query on Integer / Double field in spring boot.
Collection name : players

```
{
    "firstName" : "Lionel",
    "lastName" : "messi",
    "team" : "FC Barcelona",
    "salary" : 40000,
    "type" : "football"
},{
    "firstName" : : "Cristiano",
    "lastName" : "Ronaldo",
    "team" : "Real Madrid C.F.",
    "salary" : 35000,
    "type" : "football"
},{
    "firstName" : : "Neymar",
    "lastName" : "Jr",
    "team" : "Paris Saint-Germain F.C.",
    "salary" : 25000,
    "type" : "football"
},{
    "firstName" : "Luis",
    "lastName" : "Alberto",
    "team" : "FC Barcelona",
    "salary" : 25000,
    "type" : "football"
},{
    "firstName" : "Virat",
    "lastName" : "Kohali",
    "team" : "Indian Cricket Team",
    "salary" : 40000,
    "type" : "cricket"
}
```

And my spring java code as follows which generate query.

```
String game = "football";
String team = "barcelona";
Double salary = 250;

Query query = new Query();
Set<String> gameType = new HashSet<>();
List<Criteria> andCriteria = new ArrayList<>();

gameType.add(game);

andCriteria.add(Criteria.where("type").in(gameType));
andCriteria.add(Criteria.where("team").regex(team,"i"));

Criteria[] criteriaArray = new Criteria[andCriteria.size()];
criteriaArray = andCriteria.toArray(criteriaArray);
query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(criteriaArray));

List<Players> players = mongoTemplate.find(query, Players.class);

return players;
```

Query :

```
db.players.find({
  $and: [{
      "type": {
        $in: ["football"]
        }
    },
    {
      "team": {
        $regex: "barcelona",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }]
})
```

Above query returns me 2 documents for "type" as "football" and "team" like *barcelona*

```
{"firstName" : "Lionel", "lastName" : "messi", "team" : "FC Barcelona", "salary" : 40000, "type" : "football"},
{"firstName" : "Luis", "lastName" : "Alberto", "team" : "FC Barcelona", "salary" : 25000, "type" : "football"}
```

But I want query "type" as "football" and "salary" like *250* in it

```
db.players.find({
  $and: [{
      "type": {
        $in: ["football"]
      }
    },
    {
      $where : "/^250.*/.test(this.salary)"
    }]
})
```

and the returned result will be as follow.

```
{"firstName" : : "Neymar", "lastName" : "Jr", "team" : "Paris Saint-Germain F.C.", "salary" : 25000, "type" : "football"},
{"firstName" : "Luis", "lastName" : "Alberto", "team" : "FC Barcelona", "salary" : 25000, "type" : "football"}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Regex works on text fields. So there is no regex "like" on numeric fields. Btw, How about using range max and min ? Something like between 250 - 250 ( fill zeros - as many zeros up to max double type value ) or store the salary field as string type.

Comment: I can't use range because when I type 250 then I want all matching records in the range of 250, 2500, 25000.. so on. And even I can't make salary as String because of some arithmetic operations. Btw thanks for the comment. Is there any other possible solution?

Comment: oh I see. Np. You can pass all the combination of 250 as $in criteria. I don't see any other solution.

Comment: @Sumanth Varada you can use "$eq" operator for exact match. 
Ex. db.players.find( { salary: { $eq: 25000 } } );

Comment: @RahulGhadage I'm using spring data criteria like following.  Can you please correct the following criteria. query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("slary").is(salary));

Comment: @SumanthVarada you can use this approach, replace T with your class name --->  CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
 CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(T.class);
 Root<T> rootObj = criteriaQuery.from(T.class);
 CriteriaQuery<T> selectQuery = criteriaQuery.select(rootObj);
 selectQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(rootObj.get("salary").eq(salary)));  
 TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(selectQuery);  
 List<T> list = typedQuery.getResultList();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to build LIKE query on double field.

```
Query query = new Query();
Set<String> gameType = new HashSet<>();
List<Criteria> andCriteria = new ArrayList<>();

String game = "football";
int salary = 250;   

gameType.add(game);

andCriteria.add(Criteria.where("type").in(gameType));
andCriteria.add(Criteria.where("$where").is("/^" + salary + ".*/.test(this.salary)"));

Criteria[] criteriaArray = new Criteria[andCriteria.size()];
criteriaArray = andCriteria.toArray(criteriaArray);
query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(criteriaArray));

List<Players> players = mongoTemplate.find(query, Players.class);

return players;
```

This code snippet generate LIKE as I posted above.
Also you can do it in simple way.

```
Query query = new Query();
Set<String> gameType = new HashSet<>();
        
String game = "football";
int salary = 250;
        
gameType.add(game);
        
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("type").in(gameType));
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("$where").is("/^" + salary + ".*/.test(this.salary)"));

List<Players> players = mongoTemplate.find(query, Players.class);

return players;
```

Query:

```
db.players.find({
  $and: [{
      "type": {
        $in: ["football"]
      }
    },
    {
      $where : "/^250.*/.test(this.salary)"
    }]
})
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Base on @Rahul Ghadage answer, I was able to get this working:

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("$where").is("/" + salary + "/.test(this.salary)"));
```

Note that the **salary** in the code sample is your Java variable populated with the number that you want to match.
The second **salary** is the name of the field in your mongo structure.

*Be careful using regex in mongo with user inputs!*