# What are some of the easy ways to write this SQL in Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

What would be an easy way to perform the SQL query below in Spring Data MongoDB? Doesn't matter whether it's using MongoRepository, Query, or Criterion.

`SELECT * FROM Person WHERE firstname like '%tom%' OR lastname like '%tom%'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41749367/7975771 does that help you?

Comment: @varman Almost, but the "or" part is tricky and I haven't found any solutions without having to go to the DB twice (2 queries basically)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like following with MongoRepository.

```
List<User> users = userRepository.findByFirstnameRegexOrLastnameRegex(".*john.*",".*smith.*");

interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
     List<User> findByFirstnameRegexOrLastnameRegex(String firstname,String lastname);
}
```